# Quicksort on linked list with helper lists

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list, quicksort, singly-linked-list

I need to preform quickSort on linked list, the problem is I can't figure out how to concatenate the small, pivot and big side of the list.

The partition function works, and I am able to divide the list each time until base case.

Couple notes about the question requirements:

- i must split list (example below).
- pivot is always the first element.
- after concatenate the parts the original list's pointer should point to sorted list

for example:

original list: `5->3->7->1->9->8->2->5->6`

pivot list: `5->NULL`

smaller or equal than the pivot list: `3->1->2->5` (first run ... second .. keep divide until base case)

larger than the pivot list: `7->9->8->6` (first run ... second .. keep divide until base case)

original list after first run: `NULL`

end result : `1->2->3->5->5->6->7->8->9->NULL`

code:

```
void partition(list **lst, list **pivot, list **small, list **big)
{
    // your code:
    list *curr, *pivotEl, *smallHead, *smallTail, *largeHead, *largeTail;

    pivotEl = *lst;
    curr = (*lst)->next;

    smallHead = smallTail = largeHead = largeTail = NULL;

    while (curr != NULL)
    {
        if (curr->data <= pivotEl->data)
        {
            if (smallHead == NULL)
            {
                smallHead = curr;
                smallTail = curr;
            }
            else
            {
                smallTail->next = curr;
                smallTail = curr;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (largeHead == NULL)
            {
                largeHead = curr;
                largeTail = curr;
            }
            else
            {
                largeTail->next = curr;
                largeTail = curr;
            }
        }

        curr = curr->next;
    }

    // Close the links
    pivotEl->next = NULL;

    if (smallTail != NULL) smallTail->next = NULL;
    if (largeTail != NULL) largeTail->next = NULL;

    // connects to the lists
    *pivot = pivotEl;
    *small = smallHead;
    *big = largeHead;
}

void quickSortList(list **lst) // here is i am stuck
{
    // your code:
    list *temp = *lst, *big, *small, *pivot;

    if (temp && temp->next)
    {
        partition(lst, &pivot, &small, &big);
        quickSortList(&small);
        quickSortList(&big);
    } 
    else {
        pivot->next = big;
        if (small) 
        {
          list* cur = small;
          while (cur->next) {
            cur = cur->next;
        }
        cur->next = pivot;
        *lst = small;
    }
    else {
        *lst = pivot;
    }


}
```

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 yes , i have to use my on sorting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define this function which extends a linked list with another one. There is no magic here: you'll have to walk through the first list to find its tail, and then set the tail's `next` field to the head of the next list. If the first list is empty, then that list's head pointer must be mutated to be come the other list's head:

```
void concat(list **lst, list *other) {
    if (*lst) {
        list *cur = *lst;
        while (cur->next) {
            cur = cur->next;
        }
        cur->next = other;
    } else {
        *lst = other;
    }
}
```

Now your `quickSortList` function can be completed as follows:

```
        pivot->next = big; // Or: concat(&pivot, big);
        concat(&small, pivot);
        *lst = small;
```

Note that we can be sure that `pivot` is a list with exactly one element, so we don't actually need to rely on `concat` for linking it with `big`. A simple assignment to its `next` field does the trick.

#### Embedded code

In comments you write you "can't use other helper function". I see no reason why you should not employ good practice, but here is the same principle as one code block:

```
        pivot->next = big;
        if (small) {
            list *cur = small;
            while (cur->next) {
                cur = cur->next;
            }
            cur->next = pivot;
            *lst = small;
        } else {
            *lst = pivot;
        }
```

### All code to run the example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct list {
    int data;
    struct list *next;
} list;

list * createNode(int data, list *next) {
    list * node = malloc(sizeof(list));
    node->data = data;
    node->next = next;
    return node;
}

void printList(list *lst) {
    while (lst) {
        printf("%d -> ", lst->data);
        lst = lst->next;
    }
    printf("null\n");
}

void partition(list** lst, list** pivot, list** small, list** big)
{
    // your code:
    list* curr, * pivotEl, * smallHead, * smallTail, * largeHead, * largeTail;

    pivotEl = *lst;
    curr = (*lst)->next;

    smallHead = smallTail = largeHead = largeTail = NULL;

    while (curr != NULL)
    {
        if (curr->data <= pivotEl->data)
        {
            if (smallHead == NULL)
            {
                smallHead = curr;
                smallTail = curr;
            }
            else {
                smallTail->next = curr;
                smallTail = curr;
            }
        }
        else {
            if (largeHead == NULL)
            {
                largeHead = curr;
                largeTail = curr;
            }
            else {
                largeTail->next = curr;
                largeTail = curr;
            }
        }

        curr = curr->next;
    }

    // Close the linkes
    pivotEl->next = NULL;

    if(smallTail != NULL) smallTail->next = NULL;
    if(largeTail != NULL) largeTail->next = NULL;

    // connects to the lists
    *pivot = pivotEl;
    *small = smallHead;
    *big = largeHead;

}

void quickSortList(list** lst) // here is i am stuck
{
    // your code:
    list* temp = *lst, * big, * small, * pivot;

    if (temp && temp->next)
    {
        partition(lst, &pivot, &small, &big);
        quickSortList(&small);
        quickSortList(&big);
        pivot->next = big;
        if (small) {
            list *cur = small;
            while (cur->next) {
                cur = cur->next;
            }
            cur->next = pivot;
            *lst = small;
        } else {
            *lst = pivot;
        }
    }
}


int main(void) {
    list *head = createNode(5, 
                 createNode(3,
                 createNode(7,
                 createNode(1,
                 createNode(9,
                 createNode(8,
                 createNode(2,
                 createNode(5,
                 createNode(6, NULL)))))))));
    printList(head);
    quickSortList(&head);
    printList(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
5 -> 3 -> 7 -> 1 -> 9 -> 8 -> 2 -> 5 -> 6 -> null
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 5 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> null
```

Comment: thank you,  but i cant's use other helper function, so how can i implement the concat function inside quickSortList function ?

Comment: you right, but this is what my instructor require, so **lst and *other become small and big ?

Comment: (see update to answer)

Comment: i updated the code , but i am getting error(null pointer), i put the code inside the quickSortList function

Comment: Runs fine for me at [repl.it](https://replit.com/@trincottrincots/httpsstackoverflowcoma769934555459839#). For which input you got errors?

Comment: The input the question , the original list . Maybe because I didn't initialise the variable to null ? In the quickSortList function ?

Comment: Did you see the link I posted? It runs the code on the example list you gave in the question. All the code is there.

Comment: thank you very much, i puted the code in wrong section

Answer (score 0):

> I need to preform quickSort on linked list, **the problem is I can't
> figure out how to concatenate the small, pivot and big side of the
> list**.

You can simplify essentially the task if your function `partition` will return the position where two lists must be merged. Usually (at least in C++) similar functions behave this way.

Also the parameter `list **pivot` is redundant in this case. You always can obtain the pivot value within the function from the first node of the passed list.

Here is a demonstration program,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct list
{
    int data;
    struct list *next;
} list;

void clear( list **lst )
{
    while (*lst)
    {
        list *current = *lst;
        *lst = ( *lst )->next;
        free( current );
    }
}

size_t assign( list **lst, const int a[], size_t n )
{
    clear( lst );

    size_t count = 0;

    while (n-- && ( *lst = malloc( sizeof( list ) ) ) != NULL)
    {
        ( *lst )->data = *a++;
        ( *lst )->next = NULL;

        lst = &( *lst )->next;

        ++count;
    }

    return count;
}

FILE *display( const list *lst, FILE *fp )
{
    for (; lst != NULL; lst = lst->next)
    {
        fprintf( fp, "%d -> ", lst->data );
    }

    fputs( "null", fp );

    return fp;
}

list ** partition( list **lst, list **small, list **big )
{
    if (*lst)
    {
        while (*small) small = &( *small )->next;
        while (*big) big = &( *big )->next;

        int pivot = ( *lst )->data;

        for (list *current = ( *lst )->next; current; )
        {
            if (pivot < current->data)
            {
                *big = current;
                big = &( *big )->next;
            }
            else
            {
                *small = current;
                small = &( *small )->next;
            }

            current = current->next;
        }

        *small = NULL;
        *big = NULL;
    }

    return small;
}


void quickSortList( list **lst )
{
    if (*lst && ( *lst )->next)
    {
        list *small = NULL, *big = NULL;

        list **pivot_node = partition( lst, &small, &big );

        quickSortList( &small );
        quickSortList( &big );

        *pivot_node = *lst;
        ( *pivot_node )->next = big;
        *lst = small;
    }
}

int main( void )
{
    const int a[] =  { 5, 3, 7, 1, 9, 8, 2, 5, 6 };

    list *lst = NULL;

    assign( &lst, a, sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a ) );

    fputc( '\n', display( lst, stdout ) );

    quickSortList( &lst );

    fputc( '\n', display( lst, stdout ) );

    clear( &lst );
}
```

The program output is

```
5 -> 3 -> 7 -> 1 -> 9 -> 8 -> 2 -> 5 -> 6 -> null
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 5 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> null
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need to preform quickSort on linked list, the problem is I can't figure out how to concatenate the small, pivot and big side of the list.

You cannot apply QUICKSORT algorithm to a linked list, basically because QUICKSORT was designed to sort arrays.  From the explanation you give, you are probably meshing with some variant of a mixing algorithm for sequencial data structures, but not related to QUICKSORT.  A linked list has no direct access to tne i-th element of the list (which is required, to navigate the array forward and backward from the ends, a linked list can be navigated forward, but not backward) and you cannot easily subdivide it in partitions.  QUICKSORT takes advantage (as specified in the original paper by Dijkstra) that the distant exchanges are more efficient than the close ones, if you change the navigation order to be able to navigate both subdivisions, you will not be doing QUICKSORT at all.

The simplest thing you can do is to first build an array of pointers to the list nodes and sort that array (this time using QUICKSORT on the pointers array) and then rebuild (if necessary) the list itself with the new order.  The advantage of this approach is that you can conserve the original order of the list, allowing you to used the ordered array when you need to navigate the items in order.

I guess what you try to do, by partitioning the list in elements that are under the pivot and elements that are over, and navigate the list only in the forward direction separating all the elements that are below the pivot from all the ones that are above, but this will lead to a diferent (but somehow similar) algorithm.  Final concatenation of BELOW THE PIVOT, PIVOT, and ABOVE THE PIVOT sorted sublists requires you to save pointers to the last node of those lists or you will have to append by searching for the last element, making the algorithm fairly inefficient.